# How Can I edit the Geometry of Points when many of them lie at the same place?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing

I had some location data as CSV, and I have converted them to a Point Featureclass in ArcMap. Some of those records had 0,0 for lat,long, and hence the data went to Null Island.

I have now got the correct Lat-Long for some of those records, and I need to update the fields as well as geometry for those records.

When I start editing, and use the Edit tool, all of them get selected.
[image]

I can't find a way to select individual records, and edit their geometry.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you select these in the attribute table? Or by FID/OID with 'select by attributes'?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I can do an attribute selection, but the coordinates don't appear in the 'Edit Sketch' window, to enter the correct lat-long. & If I Double click with the edit tool after selection, some other point seems to get selected.

Comment: Not even in the 'sketch properties' window when you right click and select edit vertices? It's a good thing that you can code python, this would have been so annoying to rectify manually, it's *tedious* to enter coordinates manually and difficult to verify - even with a second person verifying the numbers.

Comment: @MichaelStimson: That worked! I'm a bit rusty when it comes to doing stuff through the UI, and my mind rushes to finding a programmatic solution. Can you post your comment as an Answer, so that I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: Done, with a few more useful tips to make it answer worthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *like* Devdattas' answer but if you don't know or understand python you can select individual records of an overlapping 'heap' (usually sitting upon [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island) indicating there was a problem with importing the records) with the attribute table by clicking on the row number.

From there you can edit the coordinates manually by right clicking with the edit tool active and select 'Edit Vertices' from the context menu, this should open your [Sketch Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q800000090000000):
[image]

Which you can use to modify your X, Y, Z and/or M values - even for a point, but like I said in my comment this is *tedious* to do more than a few times; I almost always go back a step and correct the records prior to re-importing.

This handy utility is also good for checking/finding small holes in very large polygons: go to the next part in the list, click on the top row to select the part:
[image]

Right click and either Zoom To or Pan To the hole, from here you can also delete the whole part to remove a hole or external polygon. You can also tell if the points do not have **part 0** right at the top of the list that there is no holes in this polygon.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using arcpy to solve this problem.

I wrote the following function:

```py
def updateRow(lat, lng, id):
    fields=['Latitude', 'Longitude', "SHAPE@XY"]
    query='OBJECTID={0}'.format(id)
    cursor=arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Data", fields, query)
    c=cursor.next()
    if c is not None:
        c[0]=lat
        c[1]=lng
        pt=(lng, lat)
        c[2]=pt
        cursor.updateRow(c)
        del cursor
```

I then updated individual records by calling this function like: `updateRow(20.435, 79.211, 734)`